# Check if CDT is installed in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an Eclipse for Android development, and I need to know if the CDT plugin is installed. I have both SDK and NDK installed (`adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702` and `android-ndk-r10d`), but the intellisense for C++ source code is not working at all, which makes me suspect that CDT is not installed.

But I have no idea how to even check if it is installed or not. Where in the menus do I go? What do I look for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click 'Help > About Eclipse' and then click the 'Installation Details' button at the bottom of the dialog. The resulting dialog shows all the features you have installed on the 'Installed Software' tab.

On newer versions of Eclipse you can go directly to this dialog from 'Help > Installation Details'

On Macs the About dialog is in the Eclipse menu